# How to get column index of a table cell

Tags: jquery, html

How do I get the column index of any HTML divider element in a table in jQuery? Here is my HTML:

```css
table {
 border:1px solid navy;
 width: 70%;
 text-align: center;
}
table th {
 text-align: center;
 width:100px;
 height:20px;
}
table td {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 vertical-align: top;
 text-align: right;
 border: 1px solid #c6c6ec;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Header</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Header1</th><th>Header2</th><th>Header3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Want this column index e.g.</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I've managed to get the row index using the following jQuery:

```
var text_var = "Want this column index e.g."
var elem = $('td').filter(function() { 
        var Text = $(this).contents()[0].textContent.trim();
        return parseInt(Text, 10) == text_var;
    });
var row_index_first = elem.parent().index();
```

I want to get the column with something similar..?

Thanks

Comment: To get column index just use `elem.index();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic is very similar, you just need to check the `text()` directly without converting it to an integer, and then call `index()` on `elem`. Try this:

```js
var text_var = "Want this column index e.g."
var elem = $('td').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().trim() == text_var;
});
var row_index_first = elem.index();

console.log(row_index_first);
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid navy;
  width: 70%;
  text-align: center;
}

table th {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
}

table td {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: right;
  border: 1px solid #c6c6ec;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Header</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Header1</th>
      <th>Header2</th>
      <th>Header3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Want this column index e.g.</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: elem.index() works just fine even when converting to an integer! Thanks

Comment: I assume the text of the `td` is numerical then? Either way, glad to help!

Comment: Ah yes it is in my code - you'd be right the for what I put above!